# Rails: storing static lookup types/constants outside database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, constants

I have static lookups that are used to populate form fields as well as validate attributes.

I'm not storing them in the database because they are static and will not change, and core application logic is based upon the values (don't want a DB value change breaking the application).

```
# 15+ different categories...
APPLICANT_TYPES = ["primary", "coborrower"].freeze

# forms...
<%= f.select :applicant_type, APPLICANT_TYPES %>

# models...
class Applicant < ApplicationRecord
  validates :applicant_type, inclusion: { in: APPLICANT_TYPES }
end
```

I have several options that are viable, but am not sure which one is the most conventional or may cause problems. What's the Rails convention for static constants like this?

1. `config/initializers/constants.rb`
2. `ApplicationRecord` that all models inherit from
3. `config/constants.yml` doesn't seem preferible to me since there's the extra step to load YAML into Ruby, so why not just go with `constants.rb` above?

I'm a little confused because any of them will work, but I'm sure there are some unexpected side-effects I'm not considering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard practice is to define constants in the class (or module) that they're most related to. In your example, you'd define them in `Applicant`:

```
class Applicant < ApplicationRecord
  APPLICANT_TYPES = ["primary", "coborrower"].freeze
end
```

Then when you use them, reference them via that class (or module):

```
<%= f.select :applicant_type, Applicant::APPLICANT_TYPES %>
```

It's a pretty plain-vanilla answer, but it's served me well so far!

Also take a look at [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), in case that's a pattern that helps you.

Comment: I'm a fan of conventional, "plain-vanilla", so that works for me! What about types that apply to 2 different models? For instance, I have a `Contact` model and a `Partner` model, and both have a `citizenship_type` attribute that pulls from a `CITIZENSHIPS` constant array. I'm thinking about putting "shared" constants in the parent `ApplicationRecord`.

Comment: For shared constants, I'd recommend making a module that just acts as a holder (like `Citizen::CITIZENSHIPS`). Nothing needs to include the module, it's just a logical well-named place.  ApplicationRecord is good for data that *all* models need, whereas modules are good for anything that only some models need!